# What's the difference between 円い and 丸い?

Tags: meaning

I already know that 円い 「まるい」 means circular, but I am watching a hundred of times 丸い, and I think it's also pronounced まるい.

Could you give me some examples of both 丸い and 円い？

Also, are both exchangeable in all senteces?

Comment: According to the dictionary they are the same. There is no difference.
https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/209865/meaning/m0u/円い/

Comment: ^ Where does it say they are the same and there's no difference? そんなこと書いてないですけど。 **Edit** `[補説]ボールや果物など球形については多く「丸い」の表記を用いる` って書いてあるやん！どこに目ぇつけて（（ry